# python 3.7 cannot import easy-pil

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to use easy-pil to make rank cards for discord.py. I have the problem that python cannot import the modules on ubuntu, and I get an error.

This is at the top of the file to import

```
from easy_pil import Editor, Canvas, Font, load_image, Text
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    from easy_pil import Editor, Canvas, Font, load_image, Text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/easy_pil/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .editor import Editor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/easy_pil/editor.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .font import Font
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/easy_pil/font.py", line 3, in <module>
    from typing import Literal
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)
```

Am I missing something to import, or has something been installed incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) was added to the python standard library's [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module in version 3.8 according to the docs.

`easy-pil`'s [`setup.py`](https://github.com/shahriyardx/easy-pil/blob/master/setup.py) claims compatibility with python 3.7+, so this is clearly a bug.

I've taken the liberty of reporting this on GitHub (citing this question): https://github.com/shahriyardx/easy-pil/issues/3. In the meantime upgrade your python to 3.8+ for an easy workaround.

**Update**

Looks like the is was resolved.l in `easy-pil` v0.1.1 by adding a dependency to the [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) backport library.

Comment: I still get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    from easy_pil import Editor, Canvas, Font, load_image, Text
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easy_pil`

Comment: @Michael. Pip is bound to your version of python. Each version has its own installation of each package. Once you upgrade python, you need to install easy-pil for that version.

Comment: @Michael. In case you think that's wasteful, keep in mind that it's done for the sake of packages like numpy, which have C extensions that are generally very version specific